# React-Viro AR ImageTracking sub elements are positioned inside camera when target is seen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, augmented-reality, viro-react, viro-media

I am currently using  `Viro-React (React-Viro)`  for a AR project in which, if a certain pictures gets seen by the camera a video is played infront of it. I had it working perfectly, but somehow and a few days later, without changing the code, the video and everything inside the `ViroARImageMarker` is always positioned inside the camera, when the target gets seen.

This behavior only seems to happen in my own projects and not in the samples provided by Viro Media.

I have tried to:

- Reinstalling node modules
- Compared the package.json's and reinstalled.
- Changed the position of the elements inside the `ViroARImageMarker`
- And reorganised the elements.

But nothing seems to work.

As I said the code itself shows and hides the video, but does not position the video (every inside the `ViroARImageMarker` correctly, but positions them in the position of the camera when the targets gets seen and then keeps them there.

Here is the code. (Snippet at the end)
I pass this function to the `ViroARSceneNavigator` in another script.

There are a few animations, which just scale up/down the video depending if the target is in view or not.

(I removed the whitespaces to fit more onto one screen)

[Main Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFoCZ.png)

[Viro Animations and Material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inROv.png)

```css
 

   "use strict";

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ViroARScene, ViroNode, ViroARImageMarker, ViroVideo, ViroARTrackingTargets, ViroAnimations, ViroMaterials } from "react-viro";

const MainScene = (props) => {
    const videoPath = require("./res/Test_Video.mp4");
    const [playVideoAnimation, setPlayVideoAnimation] = useState(false);
    const [videoAnimationName, setVideoAnimationString] = useState("showVideo");
    const [shouldPlayVideo, setShouldPlayVideo] = useState(false);

    function onAnchorFound() {
        setPlayVideoAnimation(true);
        setVideoAnimationString("showVideo");
        setShouldPlayVideo(true);
    }

    function onAnchorRemoved() {
        setShouldPlayVideo(false);
        setVideoAnimationString("closeVideo");
        setPlayVideoAnimation(true);
    }

    function onVideoAnimationFinish() {
        setPlayVideoAnimation(false);
    }

    function onVideoFinish() {
        setShouldPlayVideo(false);
        setVideoAnimationString("closeVideo");
        setPlayVideoAnimation(true);
    }
    
    return (
        <ViroARScene>
            <ViroARImageMarker target={"targetOne"} onAnchorFound={onAnchorFound} onAnchorRemoved={onAnchorRemoved}>
                <ViroNode rotation={[-90, 0, 0]}>
                    <ViroVideo
                        position={[0, 0, 0]}
                        scale={[0, 0, 0]}
                        dragType="FixedToWorld"
                        animation={{ name: videoAnimationName, run: playVideoAnimation, onFinish: onVideoAnimationFinish }}
                        source={videoPath}
                        materials={["chromaKeyFilteredVideo"]}
                        height={0.2 * (9 / 16)}
                        width={0.2}
                        paused={!shouldPlayVideo}
                        onFinish={onVideoFinish}
                    />
                </ViroNode>
            </ViroARImageMarker>
        </ViroARScene>
    );
};

ViroAnimations.registerAnimations({
    showVideo: {
        properties: { scaleX: 0.9, scaleY: 0.9, scaleZ: 0.9 },
        duration: 1,
        easing: "bounce",
    },
    closeVideo: {
        properties: { scaleX: 0, scaleY: 0, scaleZ: 0 },
        duration: 1,
    },
});

ViroMaterials.createMaterials({
    chromaKeyFilteredVideo: {
        chromaKeyFilteringColor: "#00FF00",
    },
});

ViroARTrackingTargets.createTargets({
    targetOne: {
        source: require("./res/Test_Bild.png"),
        orientation: "Up",
        physicalWidth: 0.01, // real world width in meters
    },
});

export default MainScene;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by `copying (downgrading) my dependencies` in my `package.json` from the [React-Viro codesamples](https://github.com/viromedia/viro/blob/master/code-samples/package.json) and `decreasing` the `width/height` (inside the element) and `scale` (in the animation) of the video.

Note that if the sub element of the `ViroARImageMarker` is `too big` (in scale and size), the `issue comes back`.